# How to gather all offline resources from cookbook before chef-solo offline install

Tags: offline-caching, chef-solo

I have a server that will not have access to the internet to download items - is there any way to force chef to grab everything it needs and then bundle it for 'offline' use? I can move files to and from the server to a bastion, that I can access from my workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked in a chat room and the answer was the 'vendor' option of berkshelf.